# Search for keyword in text and create dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to build a dataframe from specific lines of a text file? For example, search for a keyword in a text file, once found, create a dataframe from the next 10 lines after the keyword. I'm new the python and I can convert a entire text file to a dataframe but not sure if the above is possible. Thanks!

Here is a sample text:

```
do not need line 1
do not need line 2  
start to read here
data    data    data
1   2   3
4   5   6
stop reading here
```

There will be more blocks of data from which I would like to build several dataframes from once I figure out how to read the first block.

Comment: It is certainly possible. If you could post a sample text file, I can take a crack at it to show you how

Comment: Sample text added to original post. Thanks.